# Readability of || statements

Tags: javascript, maintenance, readability

On [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate) they use this code for jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-...
```

What's more readable:

```
if (!window.jQuery) document.write(...);
```

or

```
window.jQuery || document.write(...);
```

Comment: Another thing we sometimes do in H5BP is introduce clever tricks like this that lead to a better understanding of code. I think this is a good example. The `if` statement is almost TOO obvious; it can afford to teach you something at the same time.

Comment: Any javascript programmer worth their salt will be able to read both forms equally well. When it comes to inline code, I typically prefer the shortest reasonable form, so I would use `window.jQuery||document.write...` for sake of brevity.

Comment: @PaulIrish I can't tell whether it's sarcasm or not.

Comment: So the idea is to teach a trick. -legitimate- but H5BP puts a stamp on everything saying essentially this ok, often probably being interpreted as the recommended way. (For H5BP) it's a matter of what's most valued - I say K.I.S.S. I vouch for *stupid* simple code that is really obvious. Either way developers are learning how to do a local fallback, eliminating clutter around how to do that I think would be best. Local fallback is a good trick. Short circuit statements, bad trick. Teach only good tricks?

Comment: Doesn't directly address this, but see http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I prefer

```
if (!window.jQuery) 
    document.write( -local jQuery- );
```

because it makes it obvious that the document.write() depends on some condition. With the second option, you are abusing short-circuit evaluation, so most developers will have to think harder to understand what you are doing.

I generally don't expect to see code that creates output to be used with a boolean operator like that.

Comment: This code will throw an error without the presence of `window.` in the `if` condition. See my comment on the question as for why I think it's okay our logic is backwards.

Comment: Use brackets you whitespace devil

Comment: Also noticed we can flip the boolean statement logic to be `!window.jQuery && document.write( -local jQuery- );`

Comment: @DevinGRhode The final two characters in that code line seem surprisingly appropriate...

Answer (score 3):

The if-statement is a *statement* and as such does not have a result. The or-expression has a result which is immediately thrown away. Therefore, the if-statement is less complex and should be preferred.

Comment: Not so.  In this idiom, the short-circuiting term (_e.g._, `window.jQuery`) is used, negated, as the `if` condition.  There is no reason to choose one over the other except style preferences.

Comment: Semantically, there is no difference. However, the expression '!a || b' has a type (boolean), whereas 'if (a) b' has no type (or void). Therefore, the expression '!a || b' could be seen as having more grammatical complexity. Then again, I've made and seen languages where 'if' constructs are expressions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shell idiom imported in JavaScript (perhaps through perl where it is also idiomatic). If you have a team used to it, it doesn't hinter the readability (some may even find it is an improvement), but I'm far from sure that it is known by people without a perl or shell background.

Comment: I've never been at all keen on associating “readability” with either Perl or Shell. (“Gesundheit” OTOH…)

Comment: @DonalFellows, in general yes. For that use of || and &&, I don't mind.  Perhaps it is the contrast with the rest of the features of those languages which make it so :-)

Answer (score 1):

As with others I think the `if` version is more readable, I certainly wouldn't want to see logic like that strewn about a program. Having said that I think there is one idiomatic usage which is common in Perl that I personally rather like: when checking for a fatal return value, e.g. `open(filename) || die`. It seems to me this is a clear, compact way of expressing it that keeps the unlikely check out of the main logic of the code.